# C++ returning reference from function with type of dereferenced type?

Tags: c++, reference, iterator, return

In the following function, I want to take a vector `objects` and return a *copy* of one of the elements of that vector.  Since the code below compiles correctly, I'm assuming that the iterator `copy_objects.back()` is automatically dereferenced.  But I don't know for certain.  What is happening in the return statement?

```
MyObject best(vector<MyObject>& objects) {
    vector<MyObject> copy_objects = objects;
    sort(copy_objects.begin(), copy_objects.end(), compare_MyObject_func);
    return copy_objects.back();
}
```

I know there are other ways to accomplish the simple task at hand, but I'm curious to know what's going on in this example.

---

**Follow-up question...**

Using the definition of the `best` function above, I get the following compile error:

```
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::vector<MyObject>&’ from an rvalue of type ‘std::vector<MyObject>’
     bestObject = best(myfunction(objects));
                                          ^
```

Where the relevant type declarations are:

```
MyObject bestObject;
vector<MyObject> objects;
vector<MyObject> myfunction(vector<MyObject>&);
```

My intuition tells me this error is related to the original question above.  But, I don't understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Dereference" usually refers to applying the unary `*` operator to a pointer or other iterator (like `*p`). This terminology is confusing because it doesn't have anything to do with reference types in C++, so the standards committee are moving to use "perform indirection" instead.

Anyway, `copy_objects.back()` does not return an iterator at all. It returns a reference to the object (an actual reference type). You can see this because the return type for `std::vector<T>::back` is `const_reference` which is a typedef for `const value_type&`, where `value_type` is `T`. You don't ever "dereference" references. If you want to copy from a reference, you just need to treat it like a normal object.

```
int x = 0;
int& y = x;
int z = y;
```

In this example, `z` will be a copy of the object referred to by both `x` and `y`.

---

In addition to this, I recommend just taking the argument by value too (remove the `&`):

```
MyObject best(vector<MyObject> objects) {
  sort(objects.begin(), objects.end(), compare_MyObject_func);
  return objects.back();
}
```

You're going to copy it anyway, so taking it by reference is pointless. Especially a non-`const` reference suggests that you're going to modify the given argument, which you don't. In fact, a reference parameter gives you worse performance when the `vector` could be *moved* into the function. The reference type parameter will never move.

---

Answer to your extended question:

`myfunction` returns by value, which means that the object it returns is a temporary object (it's a copy of whatever was inside it). You can't bind a non-`const` reference (the parameter of `best`) to a temporary object. This makes sense because then the temporary object would disappear (because it's temporary) and the reference would be left referring to nothing.

If you made the parameter type a `const` reference, it would be fine, because `const` references extend the lifetime of a temporary object. If you made the parameter a non-reference, it would also be fine, because it would make a local copy of the temporary object.

Comment: So I should add `MyObject bestObj = copy_objects.back();`, and then `return bestObj;`, instead of what I'm currently doing?  Would that change anything?

Comment: @synaptik No, that won't change anything. You're just introducing an extra copy. The return object is initialised in the same way a variable would be.

Comment: OK.  Granted my terminology was incorrect, but the function should work as I explained that I want it to work.  Right?

Comment: @synaptik See my addition about the argument type.

Comment: Ahh, yes, that's a good point.  I might as well make the copy part of the parameterization.

Comment: Please take a look at the extension of my original question.

Comment: That makes perfect sense.  So, changing `best` to use pass-by-value, like you suggested, also fixes the *extension* problem.  You are to be commended on the clarity of your answers, by the way.  Thanks much!

Answer (score 2):

`back()` does not return an iterator. Instead, it returns a reference to the last element of the vector.

Answer (score 1):

You are performing a shallow copy of objects and then sorting the copy. `back()` returns a reference to the last element, so you are making a copy from that reference into the return variable in the caller's scope.

Comment: Yes, I know.  My question is what is happening in the return statement.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing in a reference - hence you can return a reference:

```
MyObject& best(vector<MyObject>& objects) {
    vector<MyObject>::iterator result = objects.begin();
    if(result == objects.end()) throw std::runtime_error("Empty");
    else {
        for(vector<MyObject>::iterator pos = std::next(result);
            pos != objects.end();
            ++pos)
        {
            // Might be ! compare_MyObject_func 
            if(compare_MyObject_func(*result, *pos)) result = pos;
        }
    }
    return *result;
}
```

There is not need to sort anything if you are interested in a certain element, only.

Note: the complexity for a lookup of a certain element is O(n), while sorting is O(n log(n))

Comment: This is true, but you might want to explain that you've changed his algorithm completely to involve no sorting.